# Advise Solver Loop VBA

Tags: vba, solver

I am new to VBA and have a question.

in Excell, I estimated 3 values by using solver. The objective was set to an exact value, including there were 6 simple constraints.

[image]

Now I want to re-estimate these 3 values by only incrementally increasing the objective value (thus constraints stay the same).

I am thinking a using a loop in VBA but I have no idea where to start since I am no Pro in VBA.

can anyone help?

Ciao!

Answer (score 0):

you can make a loop to adapt the target value for the solver via vba. In the vba editor you need to add reference to the solver (menu tools-> references-> check solver).

in the loop i is used to set the target, once the solution is found, the corresponding range B9:D9 is copied as from column F.

```
Dim i
For i = 1 To 40
    SolverOk SetCell:="B21", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=i, ByChange:="B9:D9", Engine:= _
        1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve True
    Range("B9:D9").Copy Cells(i, "F")
Next i
```

Comment: Engine:=1 is for the simplex method, EngineDesc is not necessary, I think